# Show that the maximum size of a one-distance set in $\Bbb R^n$ is $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

It is pretty believable that the maximum size of a one-distance set in $\Bbb R^n$ is $n+1$ (take the vertices of a simplicial complex). I am trying to prove this fact using linear algebra and haven't been able to formalize the result.

Let $\{v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_t\}$ be a one-distance set in $\Bbb R^n$. Without loss of generality $v_0=\vec 0$, so define the function
$$w_i=v_i-v_0=v_i$$
for $1\le i\le t$. Then note that the inner product $w_i\cdot w_j$ gives
\begin{align}
w_i\cdot w_j&=1&\text{if }i=j;\\
w_i\cdot w_j&=\delta<1&\text{if }i\neq j.
\end{align}

Now we aim to show that $w_i$ are linearly independent. Suppose
$$\sum_{i=1}^t\lambda_i w_i=\vec 0.$$
Then multiplication by $w_j$ gives something like 
$$\lambda_j+\delta(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_{j-1}+\lambda_{j+1}+\cdots+\lambda_t)=0$$
and hopefully this implies $\lambda_j=0$. Thus, $w_i$ are linearly independent so $t\le n$, so the size of the original set is at most $t+1$.

Any suggestions for the last part?

Comment: Can you define "one-distance set"?

Comment: i.e., for any $x,y$, the distance between them is $1$ WLOG

Comment: You get $n$ linear equations, one for each $w_j$. Put them in matrix form and you get $((1-\delta)\mathbf I + \delta\mathbf{11}^T)\mathbf\lambda = 0$, where $\mathbf1$ is the vector of all ones. Show that the matrix on the left-hand side is nonsingular, and this proves that $\mathbf\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Do you have any examples of such "things" which are not simplices? Because right now I'm curious if there even exists a non-simplex example of a one-distance set.

Comment: I have no idea but. Intuitively three points have to be a triangle, then upto symmetry there is one way to place a fourth (giving a tetrahedron and requiring 3 dimensions). I suspect there is only one way to add to the set, and you could show that you need another dimension each time.

Comment: Also, expanding on what @Rahul said, I'm pretty convinced that you can salvage this method if you just do row operations on the resulting matrix. Its not particularly nifty though.

Comment: That's what I thought. In lower dimensions one can build up such sets one point by another and argue that they must lie on spheres of radius 1 right? There is maybe (although a quite geometric approach) an inductive argument to show that one-distance sets are necessarily simplices. I mean it is just about intersection of spheres which are again spheres of lower dimension.

Comment: Salvage? $\mathbf I$ is positive definite, $\mathbf{11}^T$ is positive semidefinite, both $1-\delta$ and $\delta$ are positive so the whole matrix is positive definite, we're done.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

There's no hope for this proof to work as it stands, for suppose that you take a whole bunch of  (e.g., $2n$) distinct unit vectors $u_i$ in the first quadrant. Then you'll have

\begin{align}
u_i \cdot u_i &= 1 & \text{for all $i$, because these are unit vectors}\\
0 < u_i \cdot u_j &< 1 \text{for $i \ne j$, by Cauchy Schwartz.}
\end{align}

Since these are exactly the things you know about the $w_i$, you cannot conclude from these mere things that there are no more than $n$ of the $w_i$, or that the $w_i$ are independent.

An inductive proof might be more successful. Use, as your hypothesis, that for $k$ points in a distance-1 set in $\mathbb R^n$, with the first point at the origin, there's an orthonormal basis in which the remaining $k$ points are the vertices of a standard $(k-1)$-dimensional simplex in the span of the first $k$ basis vectors, and $k < n+1$.

(You'll need to pick your "standard" simplex; it may be simpler to work with affine coordinate frames rather that vector bases.)

Comment: There's more though: $w_i\cdot w_j=\delta$ $(=\frac12)$ is the same for every pair of distinct $i,j$, because $\|w_i-w_j\|=1$.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that $\delta$ is a fixed number less than $1$. I'm not sure if that saves us though.